# mathematical degree coordinates to meteorologic degree coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of LIDAR data that was recorded in mathematical degree coordinates( ie 90 deg is north) However I'm trying to make plots of this in meteorologic coordinate (ie 0, 360 deg is north)

I know the math that needs to be executed in order for the conversion to work however implementing is difficult.

I'm not sure working with the data as a `list` or `np.array` is best. I have currently been attempting it in array form and using this

```
if np.where((wdir1>0)&(wdir1<90)):
    wdir_1 = abs(wdir1-90)

elif np.where((wdir1>90)&(wdir1<360)):
    wdir_1 = abs (wdir1-450)'
```

However, in doing so all values in the array are subtracted by 90. Whereas I want the only values between 0 and 90 to be subtracted by 90. The values greater than 90 and less than 360 to be subtracted by 450.

Comment: How does your dataset look like?

Answer (score 0):

You need to slice the array before you apply the operation.
This way the array only gets altered where the condition is `True`.

```
wdir_1[np.logical_and(0 <= wdir_1, wdir_1 < 90)] -= 90
wdir_1[np.logical_and(90 <= wdir_1, wdir_1 < 360)] -= 450
wdir_1 = np.abs(wdir_1)
```